# acquire field name of bean validation failure

Tags: java, bean-validation

So the class I'm doing JSR-303 bean validation on has two fields with the same pattern constraint applied to each:

```
@Column(name="test_suite_revision")
@XmlElement(name="test_suite_revision")
@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = "\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d", message = "value must be of the form xx-xx-xxxx")
private String revisionTestSuite;

@Column(name="test_revision")
@XmlElement(name="test_revision")
@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = "\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d", message = "value must be of the form xx-xx-xxxx")
private String revisionTest;
```

**IMPORTANT** - this class is NOT a form-backing class in a classic Spring MVC webapp but an entity class that lives at the base of a web service. So the validation is occuring in the service.

Now the web client that consumes the web service is a Spring MVC and does have a form-backing bean which ties to a jsp with places to put error messages.

So suppose a user enters an incorrectly-formatted string into one of the two fields. I can trap for it with this pretty standard code snippet

```
    Set<ConstraintViolation<TestCase>> violations = validator.validate( permit);
    if( !violations.isEmpty()) {
        logger.debug( "basic validation FAILED with " + violations.size() + " errors");
        Iterator<ConstraintViolation<TestCase>> iter = violations.iterator();
        while( iter.hasNext()) {
            ConstraintViolation<TestCase> cv = iter.next();
            logger.debug( "invalidValue:" + cv.getInvalidValue());
            logger.debug( "message:" + cv.getMessage());
            ConstraintDescriptor<?> cd = cv.getConstraintDescriptor();
            Map<String, Object> mapp = cd.getAttributes();
            for( String keey : mapp.keySet()) {
                logger.debug("mapp key:" + keey + ":" + mapp.get(keey));
            }
```

which writes out

```
basic validation FAILED with 1 errors
invalidValue:050607
message:value must be of the form xx-xx-xxxx
mapp key:message:value must be of the form xx-xx-xxxx
mapp key:payload:[Ljava.lang.Class;@1367702
mapp key:flags:[Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@bf5210
mapp key:groups:[Ljava.lang.Class;@a49be5
mapp key:regexp:\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d
```

Here's the rub: How does one figure out WHICH field failed validation? I can't seem to find a way to extract the field name , "revisionTest" or "revisionTestSuite"
from the ConstraintViolation object nor the ConstraintDescritpor object.

the getValidationAppliesTo() method newly available in version 1.1.0.Final of javax.validation-api seems promising but so far this method throws an AbstractMethodError during runtime. Ugh.

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`ConstraintViolation#getPropertyPath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html#getPropertyPath()) method:

```
/**
 * @return the property path to the value from {@code rootBean}
 */
Path getPropertyPath();
```

`Path.Node#getName` will give you the property name. For field names in nested beans, you have walk the path.

Comment: That's it! A thousand Thank-Yous!

Comment: But this solution is not working in case of Custom class level annotation, Is there a solution to this problem?